# Confused how to create log-in in a program, verifying against pins in a database?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using a SQLite database at the moment on Python. I am creating an ATM machine program. I have a database which includes four individuals, with their pin number, their balance, name. This database is created once the database runs.  Once prompted, I have the user to enter in their PIN number. This checks each user's pin number, and then will respond by welcoming that specfiic person's name. An example is below:

```
if UserID == userIDs[0][0]:
        name = "Jeremy"
        print("Hello {0}".format(name))
        with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db"as db:
            cursor=db.cursor()

        mainMenu()
```

Now, my problem is I am not sure how to efficiently use sqlite3 here. Do I simply recreate the database for each user, so that once they log in with a pin, the database only holds that single persons record? Or is there a way (I'm hoping) that means I don't have to delete the original database, but tell the program to only focus on this one person's record whilst he is "logged in" for example. This is because I want the program to eventually be able to withdraw money etc and every users balance is different etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the database to simulate a bank I don't see why you would want to create a separate database for each user.

Obviously you should not be putting a real bank's full database in a user's local file system, so I am going to be charitable and assume this is just a toy program.

The general mechanism for verifying passwords is to never store the password directly in the database, instead use a hashing library like bcrypt (the current state of the art password hashing for python as far as I know)

Check the docs: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.3

Basic usage (quoting the docs directly):

```
>>> import bcrypt
>>> password = b"super secret password"
>>> # Hash a password for the first time, with a certain number of rounds
>>> hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(14))
>>> # Check that a unhashed password matches one that has previously been
>>> #   hashed
>>> if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed):
...     print("It Matches!")
... else:
...     print("It Does not Match :(")
```

The next part of your question: how to focus only on this person's record?

You have to keep track of which user is currently logged in, and include the user's id in all queries.

For example, if you have a table that lists user's transaction, you need to store the user_id in the table, and in the application you have to add `where user_id = ?` and supply the user_id parameter

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day!